# How can kernel modules load automatically

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I loaded some kernel modules on linux for an embedded system. When I run these kernel-modules by insmod command, it works. How can I run these modules automatically(without entering any command) at boot starting time

-----SOLVED----

I added modules' configuration file to etc/modules-load.d

Then I put modules and modules.dep file in /lib/modules/`uname -r`directory

----SOLVED----

Comment: Modules are working based on *modalias* mechanism. First, your driver should be complaint with a certain alias (you can see by run `modinfo <DRIVER>`. Second, the device should appear from somewhere (ACPI, Device Tree, etc)

Comment: I'm working on Arago k2e-evm. I couldn't run modinfo command, it gave me 'not found modinfo' error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your modules in the following config file

/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I got "not tainted" for lsmod command. Also modules are in /lib/modules file. Should I change the path or anything else

Answer (score -1):

You can use modprobe command

```sh
 modprobe {driver-name}
```